# mouse-over to peek a field after operator->() in Visual Studio while debugging

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2015, operator-keyword

I had a tiny class:-

```
class A{   public:int aField;   }
```

Below, while debugging, if I hover mouse around `aField` in `a->aField`, Visual Studio will pop up the value of the field nicely (like a tiny Watch).

```
A* a=new A();
a->aField=1234;   
    //^ hover here
```

Then I upgraded code to override `operator->`:-

```
class APtr{ //my custom smart pointer
    A* ptr;
    A* operator->(){ return ptr; }
}

APtr a; 
.....
a->aField=1234;
   //^ hover here
```

There is no pop up anymore.    (There is a popup for `a`, but not for `aField`)
How to make the cute popup appear again?

**Edit (Bounty reason):** "user1610015" has provided a doable solution, but I think there might be a more convenient solution (only a little can help).  A new solution can even suggest me to some plugins or other IDEs.

**Edit 2:**
Here is an example of the cute popup that I want.
It doesn't work for the field after `operator->`.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly the case for natvis visualizers! Luckily, you're using VS2015, where they're fully supported.

For your example

```
class APtr
{
public:
    APtr(A* a_Pointer)
    {
        ptr = a_Pointer;
    }

    A* operator->()
    {
        return ptr;
    }

private:
    A* ptr;
};
```

You will need to create a file with `.natvis` extension, for example `APtr.natvis`, with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
  <Type Name="APtr">
      <SmartPointer Usage="Minimal">ptr</SmartPointer>
  </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

Then you simply add this file to your project, like any other `.cpp` file, and start debugging!

For composing anything more complicated, I highly recommend finding built-in `*.natvis` files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0` and using them as example.

Comment: Unbelievable, it works!  That's exactly what I want.      How do you know the solution?   Where did you read it from?  Are you even a Visual Studio developer?  I have coded `natvis` months ago, but I don't even know it has such feature. Magic?

Comment: You're welcome :)  I've been developing in VS some 20 years now. I simply read a lot, that's how I know.

Answer (score 5):

The debugger doesn't recognize the operator->, but you can get the same information by hovering over the smart pointer variable and then the right arrow on the tooltip:

[image]

Comment: Thank, you understand the problem!  But your solution is not so convenient, not cute either.

Comment: looks very cute to me :D

Comment: @javaLover _"But your solution is not so convenient ..."_ Get a better IDE then.