# Visual Studio : hotkey similar to ctrl+F10 but also skip all breakpoints

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2015, breakpoints

Sometimes, when I press `ctrl+F10` at `line A`, I just want the program to resume and halt when reach `line A`.  However, if it reaches a breakpoint before reaches `line A`, it will halt at that breakpoint instead.

Is there any hotkey that acts similar to `ctrl+F10`, but ignores all breakpoints?

Disabling all breakpoints is not a viable choice for me, because  :-

1. I just want one-time skip.  Disabling them all and enabling back in the same debug session is not so convenient.
2. Disable breakpoints may also disrupt some of my workflow, because I reserved them to be used in some special cases.

`ctrl+shift+F10` is not useful either, because it alters the program's behavior.

I don't mind to install a new plug-in.

**Appendix :-**

`ctrl+F10` = Starts or resumes execution of your code and then halts execution when it reaches the selected statement. (but if it reach a breakpoint, it will halt immediately)

`ctrl+shift+F10` = Sets the execution point to the line of code you choose

Comment: @ javaLover, could you get useful information from my suggestion? If it is helpful for you, would you please vote that feature request and mark it as the answer? So other community member could help us vote it if they see the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No direct answer for it, it would hit the breakpoint during debugging mode, it can't skip the breakpoint.

Actually I also check the VS2017 RC, it has the new feature called "Run to Click", you could run your app to the specific line during debugging mode. But it also hit the breakpoint during running time, but you could ignore this action and just click "Run execution to here" again. I know that it is not the direct answer, but I think it is convenient for you to debug your app to the specific line.

Other community members also submitted a feature request which could skip over the breakpoint here:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/2221315-implement-a-new-skip-over-breakpoint-type

A extension tool:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CodeMelee.CodeMelee-FlexPoints

Which could skip/replace the specific code line, maybe it is also a workaround for this issue.

Since no direct solution for it, I also help you submit a feature request here:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/17545741-visual-studio-hotkey-similar-to-ctrl-f10-but-als

You could also vote it:)

[image]

Comment: (1) Your answer provide great insight.  I can recognize your research effort, thank!  However, it is not useful for me much because  CodeMelee is not free, and  I don't intend to use VS2017 soon.  (2) I upvoted it at the Visual site and also upvoted your answer here.  Nevertheless, I still dream that there might be a better solution.  Sometimes, after a few month, my dream come true, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39339959/mouse-over-to-peek-a-field-after-operator-in-visual-studio-while-debugging.

Comment: Got it, javaLover, I will also help you follow up that feature request from the product team. If they share any update, I will report it. Maybe other community members also have other better workaround. But as far as I know, during debug time, it couldn't skip the breakpoint unless the code was not called like creating a unit test for specific method or others. Have a nice day.